# Excel Nested Index formula with AND, OR

Tags: excel-formula

I am running into an excel issue with nesting INDEX formulas. I am trying to create a formula in Excel that searches for a specific 'word' in a column and returns the value in another column. I need to add `OR` and `AND` operators so the formula searches for a word in multiple cells and returns the value into another cell.

This is the formula I  am currently using:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Servers!$A:$F,SMALL(IF(Servers!$D:$D="FAIL",ROW(Servers!$B:$B)),ROW(1:1)),2,1),"")
```

Comment: What is your data structure ? The desired output ?

Comment: Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: is that an array formula needing to enter CSE at the end instead of just E

Comment: Might help if you made up a 4 rows up data as initial values and then showed expected results in a second table.

Comment: Thanks Forward ED. this worked!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following non CSE formula should work for you:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Servers!$A:$F,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B:$B)/(Servers!$D:$D="Fail"),1),3),"")
```

This is losely based on your formula.  it breaks down as follows:

```
IFERROR(Formula Result, Result if formula is an error)
```

For our formula we are using index to cover a two dimensional range A:F  so we are looking for something like the following:

```
INDEX(Lookup Range, range row number, range column number)
```

In order to determine the row number of interest we use AGGREGATE.  AGGREGATE performs array like calculations without being an array when using formulas 14 and 15.  It second argument can be set to 6 which will tell it to ignore results that produce errors.  The 3rd argument is where conditional checks go, and the forth argument tell which number of the sorted results needs to be returned.

So the formula for AGGREGATE will look something like the following:

```
AGGREGATE(Small, ignore errors, row number being evaluate/(condition check1 that is true or false * condition check2 + condition check3), nth smallest row number to return)
```

in our case that is looking more like:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B:$B)/(Servers!$D:$D="Fail"),row(a1))
```

15 tells it to sort the list of results from smallest to largest
6 tells it to ignore all errors
ROW($B:$B) tell it to determine the row it is working on
Server!$D:$D="Fail" is a boolean check that will return true or false.  When true or false are sent through a math operation in excel, they are converted to 1 and 0 respectively.  This means that any denominator that does not meet your condition check will become a divide by 0 situation which will produce an error which aggregate will in turn ignore.  Meaning that aggregate will generate a list of row numbers that only match your criteria that you put in the denominator.  On a side note, * acts like AND and + acts like OR.

Row(A1) acts like a counter and will evaluate to 1 in the cell where you enter the formula.  As you copy the formula down, A1 will become A2 then A3 and so on.  And as you copy down the result will increase by 1 for each row.  so the first place you enter the formula will give your the smallest row number that meets your conditions. the second row down will give the second row that meets your conditions and so on.  If you copy down more than you have results that meet your conditions, you will get an error displayed which can be handled by the IFERROR function

Now what I cant figure our is which column from A:F you want results from.  I assumed your wanted if from column C so I put 3 in for the column number as it is the third column from the range A:F.  IF you range was B:F and you wanted column C I would have used 2 as C is the second column in your range.